# Laravel FirstOrCreate or something else

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to limit only one entry in the table and I am not sure how to do it.

I've read about firstOrCreate but in my model I have:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Ad extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'description',
     'image'
   ];
}
```

Basically I want to use it for some advertising box on website but only one will be visible. So I don't want to loop over and show for example last one.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to display the first one, the last one or random ad?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin No, I want to have only one record in table, so I don't need to use first or limit or last or anything I would like to get that one and that is it...

Comment: @Morpheus in this case just use `first()` method which will return this only ad you have in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to have only one ad in a table the `first()` method to get it:

```
$ad = Ad::first();
```

Comment: Also, it doesn't really matter if you do `Ad::all()` because there will only be one record. (Why are you creating a table to hold 1 record by the way? Why not just hardcode it?)

Comment: It matters to some degree. `Ad::all()` will return an array (so you'll need to do $ad[0]...) while `Ad::first()` will return an object (same as $ad[0])

Comment: It should be accessible from the admin part, so they can change that add (image, description, title)....

Comment: @Morpheus it's a simple model, so it will be available for editing from an admin panel.

Comment: so this first() returns first inserted item, right?

Comment: @Morpheus yes it does.

Comment: and what if they add 10?

Comment: @Morpheus but you've said you'll have only one ad in a table. You can add as many ads as you want and to get one of those use `where()` like `Ad::where('id', 5)->first();`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Ok but how can I prevent them from add if there is already one record in table?

Comment: @Morpheus delete all rows before insert `Ad::truncate()`

Comment: @Morpheus `first()` will return the first record in the table that matches any given search criteria in the query. So `firstOrFail()` is also a good alternative so you can catch an error if nothing can be found and handle the error appropriately.